# Kendoui Chart Copy and Paste

Tags: kendo-ui, cross-browser

I am using Kendo to create graphs.
Users request to be able to copy the graphs with just one click.

When I use IE11, if I right-click on the graph and choose the option Copy, an image is put in the clipboard and I can paste it easily in Office documents as an image.
When using Firefox there is no such option in the context menu. Do you know why?

I have tried many options as getting the image in a data uri intercepting the export img, but MS Office does not work well with data-uri images.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a kendo issue as such. Kendo charts aren't just images, they are interactive graphical controls. It appears that IE and Edge are clever enough to allow you to capture them as images, whilst Chrome and Firefox are not. This is maybe worth a look: http://www.telerik.com/forums/dees-kendo-ui-support-3d-gantt-chart-copy-and-print-of-charts

Answer (score 0):

**exportImage** method does not meet your needs? I believe that with a bit of code can achieve the same result.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-exportImage

Comment: I have already implemented the exportimage method, but what my users require is also a way to directly copy the chart and paste it to a powerpoint presentation... no need to save the file somewhere and a few seconds earned.